# Как правильно настроить радиус OverlapSphere

Tags: unity3d

Пытаюсь найти ближайший объект через `OverlapSphere`. Над игроком будет стрелка, которая указывает на ближайшую монетку к игроку.

Например 5 монеток находятся в радиусе 5 метров от игрока. А 6-я монетка в радиусе 100 метров. Я ставлю радиус `OverlapSphere` 20 метров.

5 монеток я собрал, ок, а 6-я монетка она просто в радиус сферы не входит. И я не знаю в какую сторону идти.

Вопрос: как грамотно настроить радиус `OverlapSphere` ?

p.s. Это можно сделать, хранив все монеты в листе и перебирая их каждый кадр, но а если у нас 100000 монет, то каждый кадр придется перебирать весь этот лист. Поэтому я и пытаюсь сделать через OverlapSphere

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что `OverlapSphere` будет перебирать все объекты в своем радиусе?

Comment: Один из самый грамотных способов, как это сделать быстро и оптимально - построить quad tree. Очевидно, что ближайшие к игроку монетки будут в одном с ним квадранте, либо в родительских квадрантах вверх по дереву. Даже если в квадранте будет несколько монет, то перебрать их не составит труда. Вы никогда не попадете в ситуацию, где нужно перебрать **все** монеты, если правильно настроите минимальный размер квадранта. P.S. для вашей задачи строить дерево - overkill, не вижу проблем хранить все в одном листе и перебирать его каждый кадр, если кол-во объектов малО.